# Xcode 4.3 Shell Script synthax error on autoincrement script

Tags: xcode, shell, build-numbers

I have this script made to autoincrement the build number on every build:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $INFOPLIST_FILE)
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" $INFOPLIST_FILE
```

I inserted it on the build phases before the "copy bundle resources". I get an error saying:

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
>   /Users/ricardodelfingarcia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flat_Wars-bhkfhubvxegpazcnqcswodoejxeo/Build/Intermediates/Flat
>   Wars.build/Debug-iphoneos/Flat
>   Wars.build/Script-B6B328B815AA6F9900C26C37.sh: line 4: File Doesn't
>   Exist, Will Create: Flat Invalid Arguments + 1.0: syntax error:
>   invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "'t Exist, Will Create:
>   Flat Invalid Arguments + 1.0") Parse Error: Unclosed Quotes Value
>   Required for Set Command

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you have space in your directory name.

This will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Comment: buildPlist=${INFOPLIST_FILE}
newVersion=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$buildPlist" | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/eg'`
echo "Plist " $buildPlist " Version set to " $newVersion;
/usr/libexec/PListBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $newVersion" "$buildPlist"

Comment: @matejkarmny is in my script what is the problem ?

Comment: Hi @DarshanKunjadiya, can you submit a new question?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error: invalid arithmetic... tells you that it's the second line where the error is. So just run the second line alone and echo $buildNumber, then you'll see why the PlistBuddy command didn't work and why it gave you the error "...doesn't Exist, Will Create: Flat ..."

Comment: I am new to shell scripts. I wanted to know where it prints. In the computer's console or on xcode's log?

Comment: @rickyman20 when you run it will run your script. any errors will be in the build log

Answer (score 0):

Check if `CFBundleVersion` is present in your Info.plist.

Your script can't create `CFBundleVersion` if not present, and it stops working.
Just add `CFBundleVersion` in your Info.plist and your script will update it.